# C# create instance of type from DLL extending host application type

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

Is this possible if not could some one please explain how i could implement this to work?

So i have a C# Application and a folder with it called modules, so files:

```
Application.exe
modules/
        Application.Handler.ModuleName.dll
```

So inside the DLL it has the namespace `Application.Handle` containing the type `ModuleName` and `ModuleName` extends `Handler` that is implemented in Application.exe so to compile requires `Application.exe` as a reference.

Inside my host application i have:

```
 string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"modules/", "Application.Handler.*.dll");
 foreach(string filePath in dirs)
 {
      Assembly.LoadFile(new FileInfo(filePath).FullName);

      string fileName = filePath.Split('/').Last();
      string typeAssemblyName = fileName.Replace(".dll", "");
      string typeName = typeAssemblyName.Split('.').Last();
 }
```

But i'm unsure if i can implement the types from the strings i thought i could with `Activator.CreateInstance` but i'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly or if the way I'm trying to implement it works?

**UPDATE**
I might not have been clear but effectively what i need to do is
`Application.Handler handler = new Application.Handler.ModuleName()` Where `Application.Handler.ModuleName` in php it's done like below i thought there would be a system that returns an object of the type given in the string. if it's not there throw an exception

```
$className = "\Application\Handler\ModuleName"; 
$instance = new $className();
```

I have also tried using the `Unwrap` system that @rene suggested

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(new FileInfo(filePath).FullName);

string fileName = filePath.Split('/').Last();
string typeAssemblyName = fileName.Replace(".dll", "");
string typeName = typeAssemblyName.Split('.').Last();
FrameHandler fh;
fh = (FrameHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(asm.FullName, typeAssemblyName).Unwrap();
fh.RegisterHandlers();
```

using this method where i give it the `Assembly` name it gives me a `FileNotFoundException` and without the `Assembly` name i get `TypeLoadException` but it must be loading the manifest of the assembly as `Application.Handler.ModuleName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

Comment: Can't you use [MEF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572647/using-mef-with-c-how-do-i-call-methods-on-the-host-from-the-plugin)?

Comment: All i get is `The type or namepsace 'Composition' does not exists in ...`

Comment: I would at least ensure that the *interfaces* that are shared are declared in a separate assembly that is referenced by the application and the "plugin" DLL. By doing this, you'll avoid circular dependencies/refs.

Comment: I don't have circular dependence the module is dependant on the host to compile but when i load it as assembly i don't need to load the host application again as the namespaces and types already exists. @spender

Comment: I think you have to [UnWrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @rene do you have a working example of UnWrap?

Comment: No, I assume you can try  `Activator.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` and then let your progress know here. I have used it in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236107/can-i-globally-set-the-interface-implementation-to-use/27237552#27237552) maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a handle to the type, so you'll need the assembly path and the type's **full name**.

```
var assy = Assembly.LoadFile("...");
var type = assy.GetType("...");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: could you just update to use my code, E.G `var type=asm.GetType(typeAssemblyName)`

Comment: It's not necessary - I don't know the name of your type or assembly so why would i include it in my answer? You can find your type name by calling `type.FullName` or better yet - `type.AssemblyQualifiedName` on it within the assembly that contains it.

Comment: That's was my point if you read my question and code you would have that information and you could give a full and meaning full answer to the question...